# How to use Sparse tensors inside map_fn in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm working on a simple Tensorflow ( version '1.13.1' )  model which uses a map_fn . In the map_fn I try to multiply a dense and sparse tensors together but I'm facing some issues .

below is a snippet if my code :

```
    def wight_multiply(self ,  current ): 
        ### self.vars['weights'] is a trainable variable of shape [300,32]
        result = tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(current, self.vars['weights'])
        return result

#### input1 is a tf.sparse_placeholder containing data of shape [400,40 , 300] 
x = tf.SparseTensor(input1 .indices, tf.map_fn( map_multiply, input1.values  ) , input1.dense_shape)
### x should be a sparse tensor of shape [400,40,32]
```

however the above code throws the below error during graph compilation :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\MastersEnv\GraphAutoEncoder\gae\layers.py", line 131, in _call
    x = tf.SparseTensor(x.indices,tf.map_fn(self._scan_wight_multiply , x.values  ) , x.dense_shape) #   x[Batch , Node , Feature ] X Wight[ Feature , 32 ] = output[Batch , Node , 32 ]
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\weaklySupervisedGraph\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\functional_ops.py", line 497, in map_fn
    maximum_iterations=n)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\weaklySupervisedGraph\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 3556, in while_loop
    return_same_structure)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\weaklySupervisedGraph\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 3087, in BuildLoop
    pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\weaklySupervisedGraph\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 3022, in _BuildLoop
    body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\weaklySupervisedGraph\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 3525, in <lambda>
    body = lambda i, lv: (i + 1, orig_body(*lv))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\weaklySupervisedGraph\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\functional_ops.py", line 486, in compute
    packed_fn_values = fn(packed_values)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\MastersEnv\GraphAutoEncoder\gae\layers.py", line 113, in _wight_multiply
    result = tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(current, self.vars['weights'])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\weaklySupervisedGraph\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\sparse_ops.py", line 2326, in sparse_tensor_dense_matmul
    sp_a = _convert_to_sparse_tensor(sp_a)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\weaklySupervisedGraph\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\sparse_ops.py", line 68, in _convert_to_sparse_tensor
    raise TypeError("Input must be a SparseTensor.")
TypeError: Input must be a SparseTensor.


I also tried replacing tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul with tf.matmul inside the map_function 
 wight_multiply but I got the below error : 

  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\MastersEnv\GraphAutoEncoder\gae\layers.py", line 131, in _call
    x = tf.SparseTensor(x.indices,tf.map_fn(self._scan_wight_multiply , x.values  ) , x.dense_shape) #   x[Batch , Node , Feature ] X Wight[ Feature , 32 ] = output[Batch , Node , 32 ]
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\weaklySupervisedGraph\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\functional_ops.py", line 497, in map_fn
    maximum_iterations=n)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\weaklySupervisedGraph\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 3556, in while_loop
    return_same_structure)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\weaklySupervisedGraph\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 3087, in BuildLoop
    pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\weaklySupervisedGraph\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 3022, in _BuildLoop
    body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\weaklySupervisedGraph\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 3525, in <lambda>
    body = lambda i, lv: (i + 1, orig_body(*lv))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\weaklySupervisedGraph\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\functional_ops.py", line 486, in compute
    packed_fn_values = fn(packed_values)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Projects\MastersEnv\GraphAutoEncoder\gae\layers.py", line 113, in wight_multiply
    result = tf.matmul(current, self.vars['weights'])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\weaklySupervisedGraph\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 2455, in matmul
    a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\weaklySupervisedGraph\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 5333, in mat_mul
    name=name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\weaklySupervisedGraph\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 788, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\weaklySupervisedGraph\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\weaklySupervisedGraph\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3300, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\weaklySupervisedGraph\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1823, in __init__
    control_input_ops)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\weaklySupervisedGraph\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1662, in _create_c_op
    raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 0 for 'gcnmodelae/graphconvolutionsparse_1/map/while/MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [], [300,32].
```

Can anyone help please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , So the issue was a silly one. as it turns out  SparseTensors store values are seperatly from the indecies. the tensor input.values only hold a flat array of values without any structure.  And matmul expects both operands to be of rank 2 thus it was complaining that it can not operate on the input.values . In order to fix  this issue further preprossing is required before performing the multip